# Migrating Azure AD B2C Users from Region to Region

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

At the moment Azure AD B2C are not available in all regions. So , If I create Azure AD B2C in a region where it is available, is it possible me to migrate users later into a new Azure AD B2C, which will be created in my region when the Azure AD B2C available in the region?

p.s. copy of https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e42bb1a-7a04-4a62-9864-5c7392f790cf/migrating-azure-ad-b2c-users-from-region-to-region?forum=paas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no information from Microsoft as whether they will provide a native export feature within B2C to allow migration between regions. However you can export users between B2C tenants using GraphAPI as per [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration). One issue with this method for local accounts is that passwords cannot be migrated out of a B2C tenant, so you have two options:

1. Password Reset - You force every user to perform a password reset whether that be via an email sent to every user, or when a user tries to sign in for the first time.
2. Validate against old tenant - You modify your sign in policy on the new tenant to verify the users email and password combo against the old tenant via a REST API technical profile. If valid you then write the password to the new tenant.